# Best Solution to have a Live copy of a Database when replication is not an Option

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-replication, log-shipping

Recently I had to implement transactional replication to have a live copy of that database on another server for reporting purposes. While configuring replication I realized that a lot of tables didn't have a primary key, so I could not publish all the tables I wanted to.

Second option was to implement merge replication but that would have added a GUID column to all the tables. Since it is a database for a vendor application and vendor has warned us to not "touch" the database structure because any change in the database structure can cause their application to break. So merge replication is not an option anymore.

I have been doing some research on other available options for me in this scenario; the only thing I could find is Log Shipping. I know it will leave my database in Read-Only mode but (to my knowledge) since this is the only option I am left with and it will be strictly used for Reporting purposes only I think I can live with this.

Can anyone suggest a better solution for this? Or is Log Shipping the only option left for me?

It is SQL Server 2008 R2 64-bit DataCenter Edition.

Comment: Database Mirroring is another.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Mirroring leaves the Mirror database in recovery mode. SO you cant query or even connect to that database.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have heard about snapshot being a pain but log shipping can be a pain as well ???

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit I would really appreciate it.

Comment: (Also, why are you highlighting things like "reporting purposes" and "a better solution" as code? This is really annoying for me to read; I can only imagine what kind of havoc it wreaks for someone using a screen reader.

Comment: Now who has down voted this question and why ?

Comment: Don't look at me. :-) If I was going to down-vote it I would have done so half an hour ago. A guess? It looks like a big dump of verbal something - stream of consciousness. Maybe put some paragraph breaks in there to make it more digestible.

Comment: lol ok no I just want to know why someone would down vote a proper legit question ??? its weird people just do it for fun i think

Comment: No, they usually have reasons, you're just not always going to agree with them (nor will you be able to guess who or why).

Comment: @AaronBertrand true agreed, Im off now and again thank you very much for the advice on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your other options are:

1. Database mirroring, and using a snapshot for read-only operations. It can be a pain to manage snapshots.
2. Upgrading to SQL Server 2012, and make use of Readable Secondaries in Availability Groups. This can be a pain in the wallet.

You mention log shipping but, based on your follow-up comments I don't think it's clear that, every time you restore a log to the log shipped copy, you need to kick out all of the users that may be running reports. This is because you need exclusive access to the database in order to restore the log. This is another case of "you get what you pay for" - you can log ship to Express instances, if you want to (and if your database supports it), but it's not exactly a watertight solution.

Comment: 2012 is not an option, and this leaves me with the only option of Database Mirroring and snapshots :(

Comment: Or changing your requirements... for example, log shipping will work if they don't need live data all the time, as will something like full backup/restore which you can do as often as you want (e.g. restore to databaseA, let users query, restore the next backup to databaseB, and send subsequent requests to that, then restore to databaseC, etc. and then loop back around). There are lots of creative solutions to scaling out reads, but only a few "just plug it in and turn it on" solutions.

Comment: this is what I am doing right now backup/restores twice a day but management is complaining about not having fresh reports, so I thought I would give replication a go but as I have mentioned in my question it didnt go well. But like you said I am looking for something "just plug it in and turn it on" solution.

Comment: And its not looking good I was really hoping to get some silver bullet from you but I guess I am in trouble :( more hard work for me :)

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand sorry to bother you after such a long time the question was asked. But a quick question please can I configure logshipping from a clustered environment ?

Comment: @M.Ali yes, I don't see why not, just watch out for [things like this if you have a non-standard install](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/559435). FWIW I've always written my own jobs to backup / ship / restore, so if you use the wizard, you kind of get what you pay for.

Comment: Once again thank you very for advice I will try to avoid using wizard :) wizards are very tempting though, click next --> next and jobs done :)